# Class not showing onMouseClick Event

Tags: vb.net, class, autodesk

I am trying to get onMouseclick event in my Class which I am writing to get user interaction and capture the click on the screen to get the coordinates

The options which I see for m_mouse are Terminate, suspend, Resume and Help only
Might be a simple thing.

[image: MouseClick Event was working but now not working]

More information :
I am trying to get mouseclick in Autodesk Inventor (3D modeling) software application in the drawings interface

```
Public Class Cls_GetDrawingPickPoint
    Private WithEvents m_interaction As Inventor.InteractionEvents
    Private WithEvents m_mouse As InteractionEvents
    Private m_position As Point2d
    Private m_button As MouseButtonEnum
    Private m_continue As Boolean

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetDrawingPoint(Prompt As String, button As MouseButtonEnum) As Point2d

        m_position = Nothing
        m_button = button

        ' Start selection.
        m_interaction = g_inventorApplication.CommandManager.CreateInteractionEvents
        m_mouse = m_interaction.MouseEvents

        m_interaction.StatusBarText = Prompt
        m_interaction.Start()

        Do While m_continue
            g_inventorApplication.UserInterfaceManager.DoEvents()
        Loop


        m_interaction.Stop()
        GetDrawingPoint = m_position
        Return GetDrawingPoint

        'Debug.Print("GetDrawingPoint: " & GetDrawingPoint.X & "," & GetDrawingPoint.Y)


    End Function

    Private Sub m_mouse_OnMouseClick(button As MouseButtonEnum, ShiftKeys As ShiftStateEnum, ModelPosition As Point, ViewPosition As Point2d, View As Inventor.View) Handles m_mouse.OnMouseClick
       If button = m_button Then
        m_position = g_inventorApplication.TransientGeometry.CreatePoint2d(ModelPosition.X, ModelPosition.Y)
        Debug.Print(m_position.X & "," & m_position.Y)
        End If

        m_continue = False
        ' MsgBox("Mouse clicked: " & m_position.X & "," & m_position.Y)

    End Sub


    Private Sub m_interaction_OnTerminate() Handles m_interaction.OnTerminate
        m_continue = False
        m_interaction.Stop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub m_interaction_OnActivate() Handles m_interaction.OnActivate
        m_continue = True

    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: If we're talking Windows Forms here, the `MouseClick` event is a member of the `Control` class, so `m_mouse` would only have that event if it was a control of some type, which it presumably isn't. `OnMouseClick` is a method that raises the `MouseClick` event. Please provide ALL the relevant information, which means tagging your question with the appropriate technology(ies).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just joined the group today and this is my first post .. Please find additional information I have updated to the post. Hope that gives you more information to point me in the right direction. Thanks again for your time

Comment: I've never used Autodesk Inventor but based on my less than one minute of searching the web and reading, I suspect that your `m_mouse` field should actually be declared as type `MouseEvents`. I think that `MouseEvents` inherits `InteractionEvents` but, because you've declare the field as the base type, you can't see members of the derived type.

Comment: m_mouse As Inventor.MouseEvents fixed it. Thanks for your time and reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the actual object is type `MouseEvents`, which inherits `InteractionEvents`, and `OnMouseDown` is a member of that type. The `m_mouse` field needs to be declared as that type in order to access members of that type.